# What is the difference between "store listing acquisitions" and "new acquisition users" on Google Play Console?

Tags: android, analytics, google-play-console, data-acquisition

I am trying to get the number of installs of my Android app but can't figure out which metric I should use: "**store listing acquisitions**" or "**new acquisition users**".

Using the first one, I'm getting more registrations than installs, which cannot be possible.

My question is: In which scenarios an install will be included as a "store listing acquisitions"?

Answer (score 0):

The definition of `store listing acquisitions` and the scenario you are looking for is the following:

> Any install that came through your Google Play product page from a
> user that did not have the app installed on any of their devices at
> that point in time. This includes new users that have never installed
> your app as well as returning users that previously installed and then
> uninstalled it. This is different from first-time installs that only
> included new users. It basically shows you only the users that had the
> potential to convert.